# Calculating Odds ratio with exclusion criteria

Tags: odds-ratio, population, risk

I had a question about how to perform an odds ratio when the group has an exclusion criterion. Let's say I am trying to find the association between surgery and suicide. I wanted to control for people that attempted suicide prior to surgery by excluding them. For clarity, I will use the notation surgery/suicide to represent the groups (before the hyphen is surgery and after the hyphen is suicide) with the odds ratio calculated as (+/+  x  -/-)/(+/-  x  -/+) also known as (axd)/(bxc)

**In an uncontrolled analysis I would group abcd as the following:**

+/+ = must have had surgery AND must have had suicide attempt

+/- = must have had surgery AND must not have had suicide attempt

-/+ = must not have had surgery AND must have had suicide attempt

-/- = must not have had surgery AND must not have had suicide attempt

**In a controlled analysis I would group abcd as the following:**

+/+ = (must have had surgery AND must not have had prior suicide attempt) AND (must have had surgery AND must have had subsequent suicide attempt)

+/- = (must have had surgery AND must not have had prior suicide attempt) AND (must have had surgery AND must not have had subsequent suicide attempt) = must have had surgery AND must not have had suicide attempt

-/+ = must not have had surgery AND must have had suicide attempt

-/- = must not have had surgery AND must not have had suicide attempt

**In the controlled version only a (+/+) changes while the rest remain the same:**

+/+ changes - I can understand this.

+/- excludes those with both prior and subsequent suicide attempt. This effectively excludes all suicide attempts at all time points so the result is the same as the uncontrolled measure for +/-.

-/+ and -/- are measured in the same way as the uncontrolled. Since there is no surgery there is no surgery date. As such there is no way to either have or not have suicide before or after a non-event

Is this an accurate way to calculate a controlled and uncontrolled odds ratio? If not how should I make this calculation? Additionally, I am using an Odds ratio even though I am stating a time relation. I chose to do this over calling this a relative risk as I am getting all of this data from a large database simultaneously rather than the surgery data first and then the suicide data second, please let me know if this is wrong. Thank you!